# In Magento how can I get the product type from product id in list.phtml?

Tags: magento, product

How can I get the product type from product id in product list page?
I'm using the code

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$productType = $product->getTypeId();
```

but I'm getting the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in XXXX". How can I resolve this?

Comment: Pankaj's answer should be enough, just wanted to add that on a product list page, $this->getProduct() will return null, because there isn't just a single product on list pages, that's why you're getting Fatal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Product page, we already have `$_product` object loaded. so instead of loading product again.

You can use the below code:

`echo $_product->getTypeId()`

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Pankaj